# How to write in a SPAN tag?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="_5rpb">
<div aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-owns="js_2g" class="_5rpu" contenteditable="true" role="combobox" spellcheck="true" style="outline: none; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word;">
    <div data-contents="true">
        <div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="ed503" data-offset-key="aqkh3-0-0">
            <div data-offset-key="aqkh3-0-0" class="_1mf _1mj">
                <span data-offset-key="aqkh3-0-0">
                    <span data-text="true">**TEST HERE**</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to get my text and play within the span tag

I tried the following code using web browser but failed. Can anybody help me?

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(webBrowser.DocumentText))
{
     HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
      foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
         {
           String nameStr = elem.GetAttribute("data-text");
           if (nameStr != null && nameStr == "true")
             {
                 elem.InnerText = "**TEST HERE**";
              }
         }
}
```

***Note: I am using Windows Forms and component WebBrowser***

Answer (score 0):

try to write runat="server".

I NEED TO PUT TEXT HERE!!!